# Flutter Getx isn't updating initialValue of TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, textformfield

[image: The function that cleans the variables]

[image: The view where the TextFormField is]

If i use the same variable in a Text Widget it works but not on TextFormField.

Answer (score 1):

initialValue as its name indicates is TextFormField's initial text and rebuilding TextFormField with new initialValue doesn't have any effect. you can use controller instead of initialValue:
[Article](https://medium.com/feedflood/flutter-texteditingcontroller-class-for-text-fields-29a7740ce9a0)